# I need to read a bang from CLI

Tags: .net, batch-file, scripting

I have a simple CMD (bat) file to change selected passwords. It's been working for years but suddenly I need to change a password so it has a bang (!) in it. My "set /p" instruction works - but it ignores the bang character and truncates the input string (leaving out the "!"). I suppose this has to do with code pages and what-not, but that's beyond my scope, and I don't intend to get that deep into this little aggravation. If there's a simple answer (like escaping the input) I'd really like to know. If I have to re-write my command with super-technical code I'll just live with what I have.

Thanks in advance.

Tovian

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your code !

Answer (score 0):

Try this tricky way :)

```
@echo off
Title Password with Bang !
:CheckPassword
Mode con cols=60 lines=3
cls & color 0A & echo.
set MyPassword=Bang!
set "psCommand=powershell -Command "$pword = read-host 'Enter your password' -AsSecureString ; ^
    $BSTR=[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($pword); ^
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BSTR)""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%p in (`%psCommand%`) do set password=%%p
if %MyPassword%==%password% (Goto:Good) else (Goto:Bad)
exit/b
::***********************************************************************************************
:Good
Cls & Color 0A
echo(
echo                        Good Password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Exit
::***********************************************************************************************
:Bad
Cls & Color 0C
echo(
echo                        Bad password
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
Goto:CheckPassword
::***********************************************************************************************
```

Comment: This works perfectly and I could modify it for my needs. I haven't yet taken on PowerShell so I'm reluctant to use coding I'm not familiar with. I will definitely hold onto this code in case I need it somewhere else. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the associated to delayed expansion.

If you execute this code

```dos
@echo off

    if "%1"=="" (
        setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
        echo disabled
    ) else (
        setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
        echo enabled
    )

    echo(
    set /p "data=?"
    echo(
    echo -- SET ------------------------
    set data
    echo(
    echo -- normal expansion syntax ----
    echo %data%
    echo(
    echo -- delayed expansion syntax ---
    echo !data!
    echo(
```

that will run with delayed expansion active or inactive depending on the presence of arguments, the result will be (`test.cmd` is the code above)

```
W:\>test.cmd
disabled

?The ! password

-- SET ------------------------
data=The ! password

-- normal expansion syntax ----
The ! password

-- delayed expansion syntax ---
!data!


W:\>test.cmd x
enabled

?The ! password

-- SET ------------------------
data=The ! password

-- normal expansion syntax ----
The  password

-- delayed expansion syntax ---
The ! password


W:\>
```

The `set data` just dumps the contents of the environment, and you can see that the exclamation is always retrieved.

But when the content of the variable is retrieved with delayed expansion active but with normal expansion syntax, the batch parser will try to interpret the `!` as part of a variable reference and the result is that the exclamation is removed. If the reference to the variable is complete

```
W:\>set "test=123"

W:\>test.cmd 1
enabled

?This is a !test!

-- SET ------------------------
data=This is a !test!

-- normal expansion syntax ----
This is a 123

-- delayed expansion syntax ---
This is a !test!


W:\>
```

you will see how the parser removes not the exclamation, but the full variable reference.

So, if as stated in the question you are using a *simple* batch file , you will need to change your batch file so it doesn't use delayed expansion except where it is needed (if needed), or keep it active and change the syntax to access the content of the variable to use the delayed expansion syntax (`!var!`).

Comment: I always use enabledelayedexpansion in my housekeeping. When I changed to disabledelayedexpansion my routine works as I want it to. I'll want to research this further and make sure I really understand the difference(s). THANK YOU.